# How to create custom build profile in titanium studio

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I want to know how we can create different build like distribution, debug, release or development build using titanium studio.

Can we create custom build profile such that each of my build profile have different settings like if resource filters are applied on my project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think something similar exist, you need to build a custom tool. What about using git and its branches? Or write a script with a list of all your files and rename all the unnecessary with a ".disabled" extension?
I like scripting and automating things, if you want we can create some kind of project on github. :)

Comment: that will be great..we can build something... :) connect with me on linkedin in.linkedin.com/pub/ajeet-maurya/17/966/550

Comment: You could also try "alloy", the new MVC framework for Appcelerator. It provides support for different environments (development, test and production).